# If my input contains only zeros, say 0000, It is not cleared with a single 0

Tags: html, typescript

I have an integer variable bind to an input field . when that input field hold value contains all zeros say 0000, it is not cleared to 0 when click on the clearCounts(). 
But if the input hold other data say 1000,1234 etc it is cleared to 0.

This problem occurs only when the textbox hold all zeros.

Tried to trim the left hand values

```
set hundred(val: any) {
        val = val.replace(/^0+/, '');
        this.hundredBillCount = val;
        this.setTotalCash();
    }
```

then this.hundredBillCount will hold empty but the input textbox is filled with 0's and could not cleared.

Here is the HTML code and corresponding .ts code

```
<input id="inputHundred" type="text" numberonly  maxlength="10" placeholder={{placeholdervalue}} [(ngModel)]="hundred" class="bills-coins-input" autocomplete="off"  />

 set hundred(val: any) {
        this.hundredBillCount = val;
        this.setTotalCash();
    }


 get hundred(): any {
        return (this.hundredBillCount > 0) ? this.hundredBillCount : 0;
    }


clearCounts(){
this.hundredBillCount = 0;
}
```

Expected: In the textbox, if the input is 0000 this should be hold 0 when clearCounts() calls. ie,

Input 0000, Output 0

Actual:  In the textbox, if the input is 0000 when clearCounts() calls, it is shown as 0000.

Input 0000, Output 0000

Note: Textbox contains only zeros have this issue.
If we try to assign with another values, it works fine. ie,

```
 clearCounts(){
    this.hundredBillCount = 1;
    }
```

Expeted: Input 0000, Output 1

Actual: Input 0000, Output 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of the fact that you're using a getter to access `hundredBillCount`. This is an unusual approach and Angular treats the update rules of ngModel in another way than in case of directly binding to the variable.

Try it this way instead and you will succeed. Using Getter/Setter is wrong here.

```
<input id="inputHundred" type="text" numberonly  
    maxlength="10" placeholder={{placeholdervalue}} 
    [(ngModel)]="hundredBillCount" class="bills-coins-input" 
    autocomplete="off"  
/>
```

Comment: But in my case i need to call this.setTotalCash(); also.

Comment: done with (ngModelChange)="setTotalCash()" . Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution. Thx in advance.